How to tell browser that the password input is not for account password but is for something else, preferrably not disabling autofill?
I have a website that have login form with username and password and the browser is working correctly to autofill and manage users' passwwords. However, I also have a page like example.com/settings that user should fill in an API Key in an <input type="password" /> (that is not in anyway related to their account password). However, when user submits this API Key, Chrome and Chromium Edge suggests updating their password, which I do not want.
How to tell the browser that a password input is not a form or login? is not relevant because they use autocomplete="new-password" which is what I want to avoid already. Disabling Chrome Autofill using one-time-code completely disables autofill which I probably will use if there is no other option that satisfy my optional requirement. The autocomplete attribute values listed on MDN doesn't give me a good idea of what I should do.
How do I tell browser that this input password should not overwrite their current user's password? If possible, I prefer that the password manager still works and remember this API Key if users wish to but it should be two different entries. I tried setting <input name="api-key" /> but it doesn't work.

Apart from not having the correct semantics, what exactly was the issue with one-time-code? Are you saying that having a one-time-code anywhere breaks autofill for unrelated password fields?

@Ry- one-time-code would completely disable password managers on my browser (Chromium Edge on Windows). While optional, the requirement states it should still auto-fill in though it should not interfere with users' account password.

So you want to allow autofilling a stored API key from the site’s own password store, but without suggesting saving it to the password store (or saving it under some other account)? (Or does this only apply to third-party password managers with more flexible vaults?)

@Ry- I prefer it having a separate entry, if that makes sense. For example, my account is account1/12345 and the API Key is myapikey, I want the browser to store account1/12345 and myapikey separately instead of suggesting filling myapikey into account1.

You can probably achieve that by convincing the browser that myapikey is the username somehow, at which point the browser should prompt which account to autofill, but that degrades the normal login experience and would be a bit confusing. Have you considered storing the API key server-side, encrypted by the user’s password?
